# Is unidirectional associations more abstract than bidirectional?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to raise up a question regarding **unidirectional** and **bidirectional** associations.

From my point of view it's always better to favor **unidirectional** associations because **bidirectional** seems to be excessive and classes wired by bidirectional associations are more cohesive.

How do you think, am I right? To my mind even if bidirectional associations are needed to simplify HQL queries it is better to avoid it thus it can complicate the architecture.

What do you think about it?

Comment: My opinion is: wherever you can, don't modify the domain model just to accommodate a library/framework. Would you model the association as bidirectional were JPA not involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You consideration seems concerned only with implementation of the relationship itself.

The most important thing is that these things model relationships existing somewhere, and if the relationship being modeled is truly bidirectional, it will be much easier to program around a model which represents that relationship such.

As an example 2 unidirectional relationships instead of one bidirectional permits for one of these relationships point back at the wrong element:

```
A --> B --> C
```

... while B should be pointing back at A:

```
A <==> B
```